# SAS Proc sort different from Proc SQL order by

Tags: sorting, sas

I sorted the data set by multiple variables using proc sort and then went on to do a datastep assigning a count variable based on the sorted fields.  Running this code multiple times gives the same answer.
If I use proc sql and order by instead of proc sort and then the same datastep code, I get a different answer.
Why would this happen ?

Comment: How are they different?  Is it that you are getting a different order for the observations with the same keys?  If you need those ordered also then include additional variables in the BY statement.

Comment: What is *this code* ? Can you add sample data to the question demonstrating the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your KEY variables have duplicates where a third (or more) variable is different. And that don't sort exactly the same because you have't specified that third (or other) variables.

Here's an example of how that happens.

```
/*Creates duplicate records with variables that are different for the remaining values*/

data temp_class;
set class (obs=3);
call streaminit(25);
weight = weight + rand('normal', 0, 5);
run;

data class;
set sashelp.class temp_class;
run;


*proc sort;
proc sort data=class out=class2;
by name sex;
run;

*proc sql sort;
proc sql;
create table class3 as
select *
from class
order by name, sex;
quit;

*comparison to show difference;
proc compare data=class2 compare=class3;
run;
```

Results show that these do produce different results because the key variables are not well defined. 
To avoid this, you should also sort by the variable WEIGHT to ensure the order desired is obtained.

```
              The COMPARE Procedure                                                        
                                         Comparison of WORK.CLASS2 with    WORK.CLASS3                                             
                                                       (Method=EXACT)                                                           

                                                     Data Set Summary                                                           

                               Dataset               Created          Modified  NVar    NObs                                    

                               WORK.CLASS2  27SEP18:16:15:28  27SEP18:16:15:28     5      22                                    
                               WORK.CLASS3  27SEP18:16:14:47  27SEP18:16:14:47     5      22                                    


                                                     Variables Summary                                                          

                                           Number of Variables in Common: 5.                                                    


                                                    Observation Summary                                                         

                                               Observation      Base  Compare                                                   

                                               First Obs           1        1                                                   
                                               First Unequal       1        1                                                   
                                               Last  Unequal       4        4                                                   
                                               Last  Obs          22       22                                                   

                              Number of Observations in Common: 22.                                                             
                              Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.CLASS2: 22.                                           
                              Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.CLASS3: 22.                                           

                              Number of Observations with Some Compared Variables Unequal: 4.                                   
                              Number of Observations with All Compared Variables Equal: 18.                                     


                                                 Values Comparison Summary                                                      

                              Number of Variables Compared with All Observations Equal: 4.                                      
                              Number of Variables Compared with Some Observations Unequal: 1.                                   
                              Total Number of Values which Compare Unequal: 4.                                                  
                              Maximum Difference: 5.4405.                                                                       


                                               Variables with Unequal Values                                                    

                                            Variable  Type  Len  Ndif   MaxDif                                                  

                                            Weight    NUM     8     4    5.440                                                  

                                                   The COMPARE Procedure                                                        
                                         Comparison of WORK.CLASS2 with WORK.CLASS3                                             
                                                       (Method=EXACT)                                                           

                                           Value Comparison Results for Variables                                               

                                 __________________________________________________________                                     
                                            ||       Base    Compare                                                            
                                        Obs ||     Weight     Weight      Diff.     % Diff                                      
                                  ________  ||  _________  _________  _________  _________                                      
                                            ||                                                                                  
                                         1  ||   112.5000   117.3936     4.8936     4.3499                                      
                                         2  ||   117.3936   112.5000    -4.8936    -4.1686                                      
                                         3  ||    84.0000    78.5595    -5.4405    -6.4767                                      
                                         4  ||    78.5595    84.0000     5.4405     6.9253                                      
                                 __________________________________________________________
```

Here's the version with WEIGHT included in the variable list to ensure that the sort is correct.

```
*proc sort;
proc sort data=class out=class4;
by name sex;
run;

*proc sql sort;
proc sql;
create table class5 as
select *
from class
order by name, sex;
quit;

*comparison to show difference;
proc compare data=class4 compare=class5;
run;
```

Results show no difference in this case:

```
  The COMPARE Procedure                                                        
                                         Comparison of WORK.CLASS4 with WORK.CLASS5                                             
                                                       (Method=EXACT)                                                           

                                                     Data Set Summary                                                           

                               Dataset               Created          Modified  NVar    NObs                                    

                               WORK.CLASS4  27SEP18:16:21:13  27SEP18:16:21:13     5      22                                    
                               WORK.CLASS5  27SEP18:16:21:13  27SEP18:16:21:13     5      22                                    


                                                     Variables Summary                                                          

                                           Number of Variables in Common: 5.                                                    


                                                    Observation Summary                                                         

                                               Observation      Base  Compare                                                   

                                               First Obs           1        1                                                   
                                               Last  Obs          22       22                                                   

                              Number of Observations in Common: 22.                                                             
                              Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.CLASS4: 22.                                           
                              Total Number of Observations Read from WORK.CLASS5: 22.                                           

                              Number of Observations with Some Compared Variables Unequal: 0.                                   
                              Number of Observations with All Compared Variables Equal: 22.                                     

                              NOTE: No unequal values were found. All values compared are exactly equal.
```